# How to set nested state with default fallback state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is there a way in the AngularJs to define the fallback per nested root state?

i have the following to redirect the user to the homepage when unmatched url is found

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/operations/home");
```

but the i am trying to set the fallback per base type when a nested states are used. like for e.g.
if i get `/admin/some_thing_unknown` i would like to redirect to `/admin/home` and `/client/some_thing_unknown` the redirect to `/client/home`

I tried to use the following, but that does not work.

```
    $urlRouterProvider
    .when("/admin",  '/admin/home')
    .otherwise("/client/home");
```

this only redirects the `/admin` to `/admin/home` anything else is redirected to `/client/home`.

is that even possible to achieve that? using either the  `$stateProvider` or `$urlRouterProvider`

Regards, Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function to `otherwise` and add some logic to figure out the destination url based on the url that was attempted

[Try it out on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/z66w9/1/)

```
$routeProvider
.when('/page1', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
.when('/page2', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: function(routeParams, path) {
        //this would extract "page1" from "/page1/anything"
        return path.split("/")[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, just had to make use of $urlRouterProvider instead of $routeProvider as they don't work with $stateProvider looks like.